# Vlookup and Isnumber(search) formula combination

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a vlookup that would search the "code" and "device" and populate the "longform2" from the "device"

I already tried using =VLOOKUP("device",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("device,"code")),"longform",FALSE) but i get a invalid number.

```
code   longform  Device    longform2
aro    data      Samaro32  data
cle    data2     samcle51  data2
det    data3     samdet45  data3
```

Comment: longform2 would be the value of longform. which is text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can also use AGGREGATE to return the row number:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$4,C2))),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$4,C2))*ROW($A$1:$A$4)))
```

[image]